# Using Includes in Templates in Document Head

Tags: templates, include

In a template, I have a need to `include_once` an external PHP (an `include.php`) that contains functions that I need to use inside the template.

Included in those functions are CSS styles and an external JS script.

The CSS is inside a function in the include.php. And the JS script also needs to be in the  area.

So I need to `include_once("includes.php")` (which is in the theme's root folder). I figured I would use code similar to this:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'fst_include',20);
function fst_include() {
    include_once get_stylesheet_directory(). "/includes.php"; // load required functions
return;
}
```

Since the action is 'wp_head', that should get the `include_once("includes.php")` in the head area. I use `get_stylesheet_directory` because the includes.php file will be in a Child Theme.

Once that is loaded, then I can add some CSS with this:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'more_css',30) // 'more_css' is a function inside the includes.php file that contains some CSS
```

And add some JS with

```
add_action('wp_head', 'some_script',30) // 'some_script' is a function inside the includes.php file that adds some JS
```

I give the last two add_actions a priority of '30' so they will be loaded after the includes.php file is loaded. (Because the includes.php has a priority of 20.)

But the includes.php file doesn't appear to be loading, as the 'some_script' function (contained in includes.php) is not available, and causes an error.

So I need a way to add a `include_once('includes.php')` so that the functions inside there are available 'later' in the template. I don't think that `get_template_part` is appropriate because the `include_once` needs to be in the  section.

**Added - But Why?**

Why do I need to do this?  My template displays a form. The form's code and functions are in the include.php file. Even the form is displayed by a function in the include.php.

The include.php file is a 'package' of functions and scripts and actions and changing of DOM elements to perform specific functions when the form is displayed - and the user fills out the form and submits it. (The 'package' is the process that is used to protect forms - like contact forms - against spam-bots. It's an effective process, but a bit complex. If you are really interested, you can go [here](https://www.formspammertrap.com) to learn about it.)

The include.php file is also built as a standalone/non-WP code that can be used on non-WP pages. I don't want to maintain two versions of the code.

The form has to 'live' in the visual look of whatever theme is being used, if used on a WP site. I figured a template would be the best way to do that. So I need to get my include.php 'inside' the template so that it's functions can be called.

As for the priorty used in the add_action, that was an attempt to make sure that the include.php file is included in the  area so that I can call the function that includes the CSS used for the form. If include.php is not loaded first, then the CSS-calling function will fail.

Comment: Wow. What exactly are you trying to achieve and why? Because including php files using actions with priorities looks like total over complication...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż we don't know what Rick was thinking, but I'm sure he had his reasons, so ask nicely and politely

Comment: @TomJNowell Tom, sorry if that was impolite. I’m just really surprised with that approach and it’s really, really strange - that’s why the question what is the point of that, so we can get the idea and be able to solve the problem and not only patch it... (TBH I don’t see anything impolite in this approach or in my comment about over complicating... but I’m not native speaker - so sorry again)

Comment: Added "Why?" information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation, and limited help from the googles, I figured how to do an '`include`' of an external functions file inside a Template.

The key is to use the `get_template_part` in your Template at the beginning (after the template header). The file specified in that function must be in your Theme's root folder, although I think it could also be in the theme's template folder.

```
get_template_part('my_custom_functions');
```

This will do the equivalent of a '`include`' in a non-WP PHP code. It will '`include`' the file called `my_custom_functions.php` .

Once you do that, then you can use filters to include things in the generated page's `<head>` area, or any other filters you need, as in:

```
add_filter('wp_head','some_function');
```

Which will call the `some_function()` function in your `my_custom_functions.php` file. (Make sure that your function names are unique, of course.)

This process, which is not easily found via the googles, will let you 'include' a file and then use functions in your include file in your WP Template.

Answer (score 1):

Including PHP files inside actions isn't recommended, and is considered **highly unusual**. If what you were trying to do worked, it would be fragile, and heavily dependent on ordering.

The reason your code didn't work:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'fst_include',20);
```

Is because actions are added with a priority of `10` by default, yet your include is on priority 20, so it happens after the other hooks, not before. As a result, when `more_css` is executed, it has yet to be defined.

Instead, don't load the file on a hook, just load it immediatley so that the functions are defined, but not executed, then add the functions as actions.

In general, it is a bad idea to mix loading code, and running code. Try to:

- Load the code or autoloader
- Create all the objects but don't run them
- Then run it once everything is assembled