# How to require specific PHP files for specific templates

Tags: page-template

How can I require specific PHP files for specific templates without any hook?

Example: I've one PHP file "autocomplete.php' and once a page template "photographers.php'

Now I want to require 'autocomplete.php' file in functions.php file only for photographers.php template.

How can I do this? I've tried using is_page_template () but didn't success.

Here is code

```
if(is_page_template('photographers.php')) {   
    require get_template_directory().'/inc/autocomplete.php';
}
```

Here is screenshot http://prntscr.com/mchx6a

I've searched before submitted this question in this platform. And i got this post [load/require specific php files for specific pages/templates/post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233837/load-require-specific-php-files-for-specific-pages-templates-post-types) But this post didn't solve my problem. Then I've submitted this question

> photographers.php is a custom template. And autocomplete.php is some
>   of custom functions and some of the script. That's all functions and
>   script need to only for photographers.php (Custom Template) so I like
>   to load that function/script only for that custom template

Comment: Why not require it all the time? And why not require it from photographers.php?

Comment: That should work. Try a relative link. Use require_once rather than require. Consider using `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `get_template_directory`

Comment: @kero photographers.php is a custom template. and autocomplete.php is some of custom functions and some of script. that's all functions and script need to only for photographers.php (Custom Template) , so why i will load that functions and script in all templates/pages/posts/etc? so I like to load that functions/script only for that custom template.

Comment: More ore less PHP functions shouldn't make a difference (depending on wheter you call them or not ;). As for scripts, you should `wp_register_script` them in your default files and then you can `wp_enqueue_script` them in the template - no need to include special PHP files

Comment: @kero I think you didn't understand my question, I want to include some of functions and script, not only script, so If i want to add php function in my theme then did i need to wp_register_script?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and posted the question here [Using Includes in Templates in Document Head](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325489/using-includes-in-templates-in-document-head) .

And I figured out the solution is to use get_template_part(). From my answer (which I checkmarked as correct; the other answer didn't work):

The key is to use the `get_template_part` in your Template at the beginning (after the template header). The file specified in that function must be in your Theme's root folder, although I think it could also be in the theme's template folder.

```
get_template_part('my_custom_functions');
```

This will do the equivalent of a 'include' in a non-WP PHP code. It will 'include' the file called my_custom_functions.php .

See my answer in the link above for more info.

Comment: Thanks for help. I got help via facebook group, here is answer 

functions.php executes very early. it can't find your template, unless you hook it with a function, which runs after template is loaded. you can use wp_enqueue_scripts.

function something_awesome() {
//your is_page_template codes
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'something_awesome');


And It's working for me. 

Best Regards